# How to lazy load model properties without knowledge of the mapper?

Tags: php, design-patterns

My domain model knows nothing about how its persisted, except when it comes to lazy loading.

In order to lazy load a property it needs to have knowledge of a factory at least (and this factory has knowledge of mappers), and I can't think of any really viable alternatives.  I could perhaps make the domain objects observable, and have a service do the loading, but that seems a lot of effort for very little gain.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should add the language you in the tags, an observer wouldn't be a bad thing but this might be specific to a language/framework.

Comment: Hibernate uses proxy classes, so when you request objects from the dao, you actually get packed objects.
http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I agree with Mono, proxies are the way to go in my opinion. I don't know enough about the problem to make a complete answer, but you can find information about this all over the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have found an elegant solution for cases where the lazy-loaded property is multi-valued (which is 99.9% of cases).  Dasprid has it on his web site here, http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk/application/.  (See the App_Model_Relation class).

Basically, when the mapper is constructing the composing object (i.e. the '1' in the '1-to-many' relationship), it populates the multi-valued field with a class that implements the `iteratorAggregate` interface.  The inner iterator for this object is a collection, but the collection is only instantiated when its needed (i.e. when `__call()` is invoked on the outer iterator).

Another approach which could work is to use a 'deferred collection' as described by Matt Zandstra in his excellent book 'PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice' (Apress).  In this case, the collection is primed with a PDO statement that enables it to get the underlying data when it is called upon.

So, now my models can be utterly free of persistence details.  Yeehaaa!

Answer (score 1):

In principle, persistence is not a business of the domain model *per se*. Separate the concern of persistence, including whether the properties are presented lazily or eagerly, from the domain model. This should be, imao, a standard practice in all your work. Solve the persistence aspect once for all, and create your models without worries ever after.

Comment: Now that your question was retagged to php, I must say, I don't know. In Ruby, we use `mongoid` or `active_record` to take care of the persistance, while we care about specifying the model. You should find `active_record` equivalent in php, I'm sure there is one.